# SQL calculate number of books and list it from different tables

Tags: sql

Couldn't describe it properly in a title so I'll try to do it here:

My goal is to calculate amount of books by their ID's (each of them has a different ID, but there are several books that have more than one copy) and list them like this - Title, ISBN, Number of copies in the DB.

It would work easily if Title, ISBN, and ID of each book would be in the same table, but they are not, so it doesn't work out for me. The ISBN is present in both tables. Below is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.ID), A.ISBN, B.Title    
FROM Books AS A, Book AS B     
WHERE A.ISBN = B.ISBN     
GROUP BY A.ISBN;
```

Each time I try to fix it it tells me what could I try to fix it, but then it comes up with another error and I'm afraid I will go too deep with it. Any advice?

P.S. The error I get most of the time is "B.Title must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" and it doesn't really work trying to fix it.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are different products; please choose the One you actually use. When you get error messages, please include them in your questions. When "it doesn't really work trying to fix it", show what you tried and why it doesn't work for you. `,` notation for joins was replaced with explicit `JOIN` syntax in 1992; please don't use `,` as it's 30 years out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY needs that all columns have to be in the `Group BY` or have to use a aggregation function

But even then you get double counts, so i added another condition

Also use `JOIN` syntax as it is already aeound for 30 years

```
SELECT COUNT(A.ID), A.ISBN, MAX(A.Title)    
FROM Books AS A LEFT JOIN Book AS B ON A.ISBN = B.ISBN AND A.ID < B.ID    
GROUP BY A.ISBN
```

Comment: Also, how could I do it if for example we calculated that COUNT(A.ID) and now I want to multiply that number by another value which is in the table Book and would be B.Value.
In a non-working way would be COUNT(A.ID * B.Value).

Comment: No you write `COUNT(A.ID) * B.Value`  the sql syntax has to be like in the documantation, because else the parser will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Include all the columns you need in select to form the group, I also recommend that you use "JOINS"

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.ID), 
       A.ISBN, 
       B.Title    
FROM Books AS A
Join Book AS B ON A.ISBN = B.ISBN     
GROUP BY A.ISBN, B.Title;
```

***Sorry for my english I'm learning